# Which type of materialized view refresh to use and how to refresh a materialized view every Tuesday

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a requirement in which I need to build a materialized view on a transaction table, though it has about 671348 records, it takes more than 15 mins for executing the underlying materialized query.
The base table is refreshed every Tuesday

Please let me know what type of refresh I can use for materialized view(full or fast)
Also please let me know the syntax for refreshing the materialized view every tuesday.

Comment: The MView can be fast refreshed if the underlying query meets the criteria. This is covered in the documentation . [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#DWHSG0082). However, if you really only want to refresh the MV once a week there's little point in doing anything other than a complete refresh. As for scheduling, you should use [DBMS_SCHEDULER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI) to call [the pertinent DBMS_MVIEW procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#DWHSG8364).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! will design the MView with Full refresh.